# What is the 'Three Cube Problem' in the Mega Test?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, puzzle-identification

The now defunct IQ Mega Test had a problem which was considered it's 'most difficult' called the Three Cube problem. Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it this one?

> What is the maximum number of completely bounded volumes that can be formed by three interpenetrating cubes, considering only the surfaces of the cubes as bounds and counting only volumes that are not further subdivided?

Found at this link:

> https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14472537